# can't upload jpg files to private server on ububtu - error Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, ubuntu-14.04

I'm taking Mattan Griffel's Ruby on Rails course on OneMonth.com where we create a Pinterest clone. I'm at a part where I set up ImageMagick on my computer, after that I set up paperclip version 4.2.
Then I edited the "new.html.erb" file so that I can upload images.

I'm getting an odd error, I can upload GIF files just fine but when I try to upload a JPEG I get this weird message on the page.

> 2 errors prohibited this pin from being saved:
>
> Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
>
> Image Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

[image: Odd error]

It doesn't go into an error page, all it does is just display this message on the upload page which allows me to try with another image.

In the file app/models/pin.rb the code looks like this:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
end
```

I think the file should have some impact on this although it doesn't, removing the JPG and JPEG in the file doesn't have any impact. It doesn't even make the site prevent me from uploading GIFs if I remove them from the code.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system. Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4-ish. A lot of others who asked a similar question about this error had either a mac or a windows PC and each of them got a very different answer since they each tried to do something different.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is a problem with the version of imagemagick that I have in my computer. Maybe it isn't compatible with my version of linux ubuntu.

The problem doesn't exist in the Heroku server when I uploaded it. It isn't that big a deal since it's only a local problem.